# Want to open a popup window and keep it open on top of parent window

Tags: popup

This has been asked but not in the way I want to use it. I have a form. I want to open a popup window that will contain all the possible values for one of the fields on the form. The user should be able to enter a value in the parent window while the popup window is still on top. When they're done, they have to close the popup with a close button on one of the windows.

Comment: first of all, what programming language are you using?
why not use a Combo Box that only accepts a given set of values?

Comment: probably will be javascript. Script is php. Don't want combo box cause if it's not in list user will type their own.